# Wildcard at the beginning of an XPath for XSLT (over multiple articles)

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a working scenario but don't know why a particular XPath is working. I iterate over three articles from a database, they are TEI XML. For all of them, I need to put endnotes at the end of a particular article (third in this case).

```
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:text">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:body"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*//tei:note"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If I use just `//tei:note`, notes from the third article are present in all articles. If I use `*//tei:note`, it works as expected. Am I anchoring the notes to some context or so?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post a small, but complete example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//tei:note` returns all `note` elements within current XML document, ignoring the context element. Commonly, you put a dot (`.`) at the beginning to make it relative to the context element.

Regarding your working XPath, basically `*` gets direct child elements, of any name, from current context element. So yes, you can say that you're *'anchoring'* subsequent XPath, `//tei:note`, to direct child of current contex element by saying `*//tei:note`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped, I was very close!